# Order Model for a Market Place Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, e-commerce

I've created a Marketplace application on ruby on rails and would like to request a review of my code (Order Model) to check if I am in the right track or not...please kindly understand that I am a super webdev rookie and would really appreciate the kindness of the tech community to get useful advice and/or guidance. Many thanks.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :ensure_login_has_a_value

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :mobile_number, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :total, presence: true,  numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 1.50}

  after_validation :create_order_profile

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :order_articles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, through: 'order_articles'
  enum :status, %i[:complete, :incomplete]

  private

  def ensure_login_has_a_value
    if login.nil?
      self.login = email unless email.blank?
    end
  end

  def add_article(product, quantity)
    order_article = order_articles.find(article: article_description)
    order_article.update(quantity: order_article.quantity + quantity, price: article.price)
  end

  def subtotal
    order_article.sum(&:subtotal)
  end

  def tax_amount
    subtotal * .10
  end

  def total_amount
    total = subtotal + tax_amount
  end

  def complete_order
    update!(status: :complete)
    order_articles.each(&:complete_order_article)
  end

  def incomplete_order
    update!(status: :incomplete)
    order_articles.each(&:incomplete_order_article)
  end


end
```